# Hamcrest: how to use either/or combinable matchers with Collections

Tags: java, junit, junit4, matcher, hamcrest

I am writing some JUnit/Aqruillian class test to test some persistence methods with Hibernate. So I have to get many lists of Hibernate entities from DB and to better write my tests I am using JUnit Hamcrest framework.
In this moment, I would like to use combinable matchers, in particular either/or ones. I know I could replace it with `anyOf()` method but for reasons of legibility of my code I would prefere combinable matchers.
I cannot understand how to use `or()` method. Here is a simple example:

```
@Test
public void EitherOrMatcherSimple() {
    List<String> keywords = Arrays.asList("1");
    assertThat(keywords, CombinableMatcher.either(empty()).
                                           or(nullValue()).
                                           or(both(hasItem("1")).and(hasItem("2"))));
}
```

In this way, I always get an error from Eclipse like:

```
The method or(Matcher<? super Collection<? extends Object>>) in the type CombinableMatcher<Collection<? extends Object>> is not applicable for the arguments (CombinableMatcher<Iterable<? super String>>)
```

So, I don't understand how to use that method, either what it expects as arguments. I know `.or()` method has `Matcher<? super X> other` as argument which is a unclear syntax to me.

I just knew either/or both/and methods were introduced to better write and read Java conditions with `&&` and `||` operators.

Would someone please explain me?

Comment: Interesting question. Which version of Java are you using? If it is Java 7 you might need some type hints within these method calls - or casts. In case none of these help, please drop me a comment on Monday. I will then have a closer look.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it is hard to combine Hamcrest matchers type-safe. Your example is one of these cases. It may even be impossible to get it right without an explicit cast.

This is a solution for getting rid of the compiler problem:

```
assertThat(
    keywords,
    CombinableMatcher.either(empty())
                     .or(nullValue())
                     .or((Matcher<? super Collection<?>>) both(hasItem("1")).and(hasItem("2")))
);
```

If I understand it correctly then the problem is the too strict signature of `hasItem`:

```
org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<? super T>> hasItem(T item)
```

Comment: Assuming this works... It is basically what I would have tried, too!

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer. It seems to work. Now I begin to understand what developers mean for "generics hell". Anyway, in this case the most big difficult thing to understand is that `.and()` and `.or()` methods seem to infer types from LHS from respectively `.both()` and `either()` methods, which must be the same. I mean, I cannot write something like this:

Comment: `assertThat(keywords, either(empty()).
        or(nullValue()).
        or(both(hasSize(1)).and((Matcher)hasItem("2"))));`

Comment: without an implicit cast to generic `Matcher` and a `@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })` annotation... it is not so powerful after all.